# What is the keyboard shortcut to capture screenshots using Capture for Jira?

Tags: keyboard, jira, screenshot, capture

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CAPTURE/Taking+screenshots says

"Keyboard shortcut
Capture for JIRA allows you to configure a keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot at any time. This allows you to capture bugs that might only occur during mouse interaction.

The configuration can be set in the server settings overlay in the browser extension's sidebar."

I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a setting in the browser extension, not in the JIRA add-on.

In your JIRA, in the "Capture" menu at the top, there's a link to install the browser extension. Make sure you've installed the extension first.

Then, when you open the extension, you can click the settings icon at the bottom. That will display the settings panel where you can configure your shortcut keys:

[image]

Comment: This works as expected in Chrome but we could not get it to function with Firefox. Luckily, I use Chrome. Not so lucky for my co-worker.